# Dynamically set form field values in React + Redux

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, reducers

My app's store has a `store.authState` subtree. In this subtree, there are three things, an `authToken`, an `isFetching` boolean and, most importantly a `fields` object. My form contains two fields : `username` and `password`.

I have created an action called `SET_FORM_FIELD_VALUE` which should generate and update each field's state as they are changed by the user.

I would like my `SET_FORM_FIELD_VALUE` to update the `fields` object. If a user normally fills in both `username` and `password` fields, my `store.authState` should look like this:

```
{
    authToken: undefined,
    isFetching: false,
    fields: {
        username: "Brachamul",
        password: "azerty123"
    }
}
```

However, it seems that my current code actually just overwrites everything and I end up with :

```
{
    field: {
        username: "Brachamul"
    }
}
```

The data in the field changes based on what field I last edited. It's either username or password.

Here is my code :

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_FORM_FIELD_VALUE':
        let field = {} // create a "field" object that will represent the current field
        field[action.fieldName] = action.fieldValue // give it the name and value of the current field
        return { ...state.fields, field }
```

How can I change it to fix my issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Your return is wrong, it should be something like this

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_FORM_FIELD_VALUE':
             return {
                   ...state,
                   fields: {
                         ...state.fields,
                         [action.fieldName] : action.fieldValue
                   }
             }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i used `change()` from 'redux-form'

which only re rendered that specific form input, and isued it pretty often.
everytime the user clicked a dropdown menu it suggested values in 2 input fields

i abstracted away the html from the anwser and some other stuff.

```
import { FieldArray, Field, change, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';


class WizardFormThirdPage extends react.component{

runInject(target,value){
    target.value= value; // sets the client html to the value
    // change (formName, Fieldname, Value) in the state
    this.props.dispatch(change('spray-record', target.name, value))
  }

injectFormvalues(){

      var tr = div.querySelector(".applicator-equipment");
      var name = div.querySelector("select").value;
      if(!name.includes("Select Employee")){
        // var inputs = tr.querySelectorAll("input");

        var employeeDoc= findApplicatorByName(name); // synchronous call to get info
        tractor = tr.querySelector("input")
        sprayer = tr.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
        // here i send off the change attribute
        this.runInject(tractor,Number(employeeDoc.default_t))
        this.runInject(sprayer,Number(employeeDoc.default_s));
}

}


// you have to connect it get the dispatch event.
export default connect(state => ({
  enableReinitialize: true,
}))(reduxForm({
  form: "myFormName", //                 <------ same form name
  destroyOnUnmount: false, //        <------ preserve form dataLabel
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
  validate,
})(WizardFormThirdPage));
```